# PHP warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home5/.../php/symfony/command/sfCommandManager.class.php

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, bluehost

> array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   /home5/.../php/symfony/command/sfCommandManager.class.php

is the error I'm getting.

I am trying to set up a Symfony 1.4 project using Bluehost, and I receive this error in the error log when I try to run symfony generate:project project name.

Comment: Wheres yo code brah? And I would assume that the parameter you are sending into `array_shift()` is not being set properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `array_shift()` the parameter! Look this example:

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$fruit = array_shift($stack); // Here you give the parameter
print_r($fruit);
```

You give the **null** parameter on `array_shift()` and you need to change it!

**Update:**

`array_shift()` shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched. Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) for more

Comment: Did you mean to `print_r($fruit)` instead of `$stack`?

Comment: Yes you are right. I take it from PHP Documentation and they did it wrong. I edit now. Thanks a lot. Good eye @PRPGFerret!