# Product Attributes in Short Description in WooCommerce 3.0+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I’ve been trying to use the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528392/add-attributes-to-short-description-in-woocommerce-3-0) like this:

```
// For WooCommerce Version 3.0+ (only)
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_attributes_display', 20 );
function custom_attributes_display(){

    // Just for product category archives pages
    if(is_product_category()){
        global $product;

        // the array of attributes names
        $attribute_names = array('pa_guaranteed-ram', 'pa_cpu', 'pa_disk', 'pa_traffic');
        foreach( $attribute_names as $key => $attribute_name ) {

            // For WooCommerce version 3.0+
            $product_id = $product->get_id(); // WC 3.0+

            // Getting the value of an attribute (OK for WC 3.0+)
            $attribute_value = array_shift(wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, $attribute_name));

            // Displays only if attribute exist for the product
            if(!empty($attribute_value)){ // Updated
                echo $attribute_value;

                // Separating each number by a " / "
                if($key < 3) echo ' / ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I always end up with error: *Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string in ../functions.php on line 51* which is this line:

`echo $attribute_value;`

Each of the four attributes I’m trying to pull terms from only have one value so I’m not sure if the array_shift is part of the problem, but it still doesn’t work when removed.

I also checked out [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500286/woocommerce-get-list-of-attribute-values) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027149/php-warning-array-shift-expects-parameter-1-to-be-array-null-given-in-home5) [posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141721/object-of-class-wp-error-could-not-be-converted-to-string) and [guides](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143715/custom-taxonomy-template-error-catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-wp-error) and still couldn't get it figured out.. I'm a PHP novice and any help is appreciated, and sorry if I've posted incorrectly.

This post is not a duplicate of any other post because the other post has a bunch of people saying it works and "thanks!" when it does NOT work for me, so clearly my situation is different.... also, I couldn't post comments on the other post due to being new so how was I supposed to get help?? lol

Comment: instead of echo do var_dump so that you will come to know what is the value. You should be getting array there.

Comment: follow this https://isabelcastillo.com/woocommerce-product-attributes-functions maybe help you.

Comment: Try to use $product->id instead of $product_id in wc_get_product_terms()

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I actually tried that on my own through trial and error, and again with your exact updated code earlier,and I still get same error. I will try again though.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec just tried it, same error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string in ..functions.php on line 50 which is "echo $attribute_value;" line

Comment: I edited the erroring line and included var_Dump() and this is what gets echoed:

_object(WP_Term)#1647 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(333) ["name"]=> string(4) "96MB" ["slug"]=> string(4) "96mb" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(333) ["taxonomy"]=> string(17) "pa_guaranteed-ram" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(1) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "3" } /_

I chopped off last 3/4 due to space

Comment: @momen-mohamed same result when i use $product->id instead of $product_id, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: WP and Woo are both on latest version, WC being 3.1.2. Yes you are correct about 96MB.... technically I want labels and colons like this "RAM: 96MB<br />
CPU: 1-Shared<br />
Disk: 6GB<br />
Traffic: 200GB<br />" not slashes, but I was going to figure that out later

Comment: I have make a last update… It will work for simple product only that have attributes set in… Its all automated now ( but you can always replace the attribute automation by a choice as you will see)… I hope this time it will work. If not contact me through my profile...

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Well I guess I'm screwed then. These are External products, not Simple. I tried it any way and it didn't output anything on page.

Also, your code is missing an ending single quote on _'Liito,_ in  _// $attributes_taxonomy = array('pa_nopeus' => 'Nopeus', 'pa_liito' => 'Liito, 'pa_vakaus' => 'Vaukaus' );_ line 16

Thanks again for the help, I'll have to find another way to do this it seems.

Comment: This seems to be getting me what I wanted:

_// Compatibility for WC 3+ and automation enhancements
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_attributes_display', 20 );
function custom_attributes_display() {
  $product = wc_get_product();
  echo '<div class="custom-attr"><div class="attr-ram">RAM: <strong>' .  . $product->get_attribute( 'pa_disk' ) . '</strong></div>';
  echo '<div class="attr-traffic">Traffic: <strong>' . $product->get_attribute( 'pa_traffic' ) . '</strong></div></div>';
}`_

(removed 2 attributes due to character limits)

Answer (score 0):

Your exec code should effectively be using `$product->id` Instead of `$product->get_id()`.

```
// For WooCommerce Version 3.0+ (only)
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_attributes_display', 20 );
function custom_attributes_display(){

    // Just for product category archives pages
    if(is_product_category()){
        global $product;

        // the array of attributes names
        $attribute_names = array('pa_guaranteed-ram', 'pa_cpu', 'pa_disk', 'pa_traffic');
        foreach( $attribute_names as $key => $attribute_name ) {

            // Getting the value of an attribute (OK for WC 3.0+)
            $attribute_value = array_shift(wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute_name));

            // Displays only if attribute exist for the product
            if(!empty($attribute_value)){ // Updated
                echo $attribute_value;

                // Separating each number by a " / "
                if($key < 3) echo ' / ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string in ../functions.php on line 46_

Same error, same line. Thanks for trying to help me though.